# Can someone explain the role of "ConnectWorldUpdateBegin()" function?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo Version : 7.13.1 
Ubuntu 16.04 
As a newbie, I tried a lot to understand the use of above function but I am not able to understand it fully. It would be really helpful, if someone can explain it with an example. It would be even nice, if someone can explain line number 143 and 144 in [LiftDragPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/01c7f8b1d68448bc618b575ad1c7ec13fee2b87f/plugins/LiftDragPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19883/can-someone-explain-the-role-of-%22connectworldupdatebegin()%22-function-?/) by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[lines 143-144 of LiftDragPlugin.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/01c7f8b1d68448bc618b575ad1c7ec13fee2b87f/plugins/LiftDragPlugin.cc#lines-143,144):

```
this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          std::bind(&LiftDragPlugin::OnUpdate, this));
```

---

*Short Answer:*
This passes your Plugin's Update method (in this case, `LiftDragPlugin::OnUpdate`) as a callback function to the Gazebo Simulator's Events class instance, allowing Gazebo to call your Plugin's method (`LiftDragPlugin::OnUpdate`) at every simulation time step.

*Long Answer:*

- You write a Gazebo Plugin to affect the simulation - in this case the `LiftDragPlugin` applies rudimentary lift and drag forces to the attached model.
- In order for the `LiftDragPlugin` to apply these forces in the simulation, it needs to, *at every simulation time step*, 1) determine the attached model's orientation relative to gravity plane, determine model's velocity, etc., 2) carry out some simple lift-drag calculations, and 3) apply the appropriate lift-drag forces.
- Therefore, in your Gazebo Plugin, you create a `Update`, `OnUpdate`, `RunEverySimulationTimeStep`, etc. method - here it's `LiftDragPlugin::OnUpdate`, that contains the code that should be run at each simulation time step, and you pass that method *(or rather a reference to that method)* to the Gazebo Simuator's Event class instance as a callback function: `event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(...)`.
- Now at each simulation time step, the Gazebo Simulator will call the `LiftDragPlugin::OnUpdate` method and everybody lives happily ever after.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on 2018-07-06**:
Thanks a lot for the explanation.